# Use jQuery to get part of JSON value and inject it into a div

Tags: jquery, html, json, extract, inject

I am working with a JSON that contains chunks of HTML values. Below is a simplified version of the JSON to help you visualize:

```
{
"header" : "<a class='widget'>widget</a>
            <a class='widget'>widget</a>
            <ul class='header'>
                 <li>link1</li>
                 <li>link2</li>
                 <li>link3</li>
            </ul>"
            <a class='random'>random link</a>
            <a class='random'>random link</a>,

"footer" : "<a class='social'>social</a>
            <a class='social'>social</a>
            <ul class='footer'>
                 <li>link1</li>
                 <li>link2</li>
                 <li>link3</li>
            </ul>"
 }
```

I'm having trouble finding a way to load the JSON, extract 'ul.header', and inject it into a div (using jQuery):

```
<div class="giveMeHeaderList"></div>
```

The end result should look like this:

```
<div class="giveMeHeaderLinks">
    <ul class='header'>
        <li>link1</li>
        <li>link2</li>
        <li>link3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

(I apologize if the JSON is of incorrect format, as I typed it up quick and am only using it for display purposes)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cnvT7/)

```
var obj = JSON.parse(json);

$('.giveMeHeaderList').append($('<div>' + obj.header + '</div>').find('ul.header'));
```

Comment: This is great. However, I actually have no control over the JSON so I'm not able to turn it into a variable. Is there a way I can achieve this without touching the JSON?

Comment: Nvm! I just changed 'obj.header' to 'data.header' and it worked like a gem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have this JSON:

> `htmltext =  {"header": "<span><ul><a class='widget'>widget</a></ul></span>", "footer":"<a class='foot'>footer</a>"}`

and you have the following html code:

```
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="giveMeHeaderList">test</div>
</body>
```

Running the following JS will produce what you want:

`$(".giveMeHeaderList").append($(htmltext.header).find('ul'));`

using jQuery .find, to find the `<ul>` element within the html and append it to the relevant .

htmltext is where your JSON sits, and `header` is the relevant JSON element

Comment: In my tests, doing this will append the entire value. I only need a specific part of that value. In my example, I would like ONLY the <ul> with no <a> tags.

Comment: @NickJ Would appreciate your input on my answer

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is :

```
$.post("url/", {},
        function (data/*({header: "<ul>...</ul>"})*/, textStatus) {
          $("#giveMeHeaderLinks").html(data.header)
        }, 
"json");
```

but, you need inject only part of header value, try this;

```
$.post("url/", {},
        function (data, textStatus) {
          $("#giveMeHeaderLinks").append($("<div>"+data.header+"</div>").find("ul.header"));
        }, 
"json");
```